# Why can't I interact with elements within the iframe?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to parse and manipulate some data via Selenium and Java (using Firefox as a browser and Ubuntu as an OS).

I want to type to `<textarea>` within an `<iframe>`:

**Main Form:**

```
...
<a class="sendMessegeLink" onclick="open_iframe('...)" title="someText">
    <img style="padding-left:5px; vertical-align:middle" src="..."/>
                               someText
</a>
...
   <table id="open_iframe_overlay"><tr><td>
    <div id="open_iframe_wrapper">
        <div id="open_iframe_closeButton" onclick="close_iframe()">&times;</div>
        <iframe id="open_iframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
    </td></tr></table>
...
```

**Iframe:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="he" lang="he">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="he" />
<meta name="description" content="someText1" />
<title>someText2</title>
...
<body>
<center>
    <div id="pageBackground">
        <div id="topBackground"></div>
        <div id="formDiv">
            <form name="myForm" method="post">
                                     ...
                <div class="label" style="width:90px"> someText3 </div><div id="inputText"><input type="text" name="messegeTitle" maxlength="50" lang="he" value="someText4" /></div>
                <div class="label" style="width:80px">someText5</div><div id="inputTextArea" style="text-align:right">
                    <textarea name="messegeBody" lang="he" style="height:82px; margin-bottom:5px"></textarea><br />
                </div>
                <div id="send">
                    <input type="button" value="someText6" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.title='... '; if (!submitThis('...','myForm','sendMessage')) {this.disabled=false; this.title=''; return false;}" /><br />
                    someText7
                </div>
                                    ...
            </form>
        </div><!--formDiv-->
    </div><!--pageBackground-->
</center>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">document.myForm.messegeBody.focus();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My code to click button that pops the iframe:

```java
WebElement tmpElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".."));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", tmpElement);
super.waitForDriver(10);
```

I have tried:

```
WebDriver pop = driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandle());
```

and:

```
WebDriver pop = driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

but:

```
pop.findElement(By.cssSelector("#inputTextArea>textarea")).sendKeys("..");
```

both give me:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#inputTextArea>textarea"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to switch into the iframe first (avoid using index, try find it by id or xpath/css selector)

```
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#open_iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#inputTextArea>textarea")).sendKeys("..");

// if you need switch out of iframe
// driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a rule called "same origin policy". Your iframe url must begin with the same thing as your parent document does - if so, you can access it and read/write/execute whatever (if there is no specific restriction by the browser; for that case there is no solution, for certain reasons).

Remember that http://www.somethi.ng is not the same as http://somethi.ng!

Read more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy